# Why can't I see my build phases tab in my XCode project?

Tags: ios, xcode5

When I click on my project in XCode 5, I can't see the build phases tab where I can link binaries with libraries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure to have the target of your project selected, as opposed to the actual project, in the left pane of the main view.

Comment: Please remember to upvote my question as well if you found the Q&A useful!